# Python's enumerate for C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In Python there is `enumerate` which takes a sequence/iterator and yields pairs of an integer index and the value itself. In C++ I occasionally find myself writing

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != vector.size(); ++i) {
    auto const &elem = vector[i];
    // ...
```

Similar to Python I would like to write

```
for (auto const &it : enumerate(vector)) {
    // it.first is the index (size_t)
    // it.second is the element (T const&)
```

Does such an `enumerate` exist in either the STL or a common library like Boost?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure why would you choose the second snippet over the first.

Comment: @freakish I can see it. Counter variables are a bit ew :) But to bring in a 3rd party library for it doesn't seem worthwhile.

Comment: @freakish you never wanted that? What if you have a range based for loop that only in some branch needs the index?

Comment: Only a couple of days old: http://reedbeta.com/blog/python-like-enumerate-in-cpp17/

Comment: @freakish: Another nice aspect is that one can use the index in an `std::transform` with this.

Comment: @MartinUeding that's a nice example. Although I'm referring to the concrete case you've posted, i.e. the for loop.

Comment: [std::views::enumerate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) is a C++23 solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is what [Boost's adapators::indexed](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html) does.

Their example (which also uses the now-redundant Boost.Assign for terse container initialisation) follows:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/indexed.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::assign;
    using namespace boost::adaptors;

    std::vector<int> input;
    input += 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90;

    for (const auto& element : input | indexed(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Element = " << element.value()
                  << " Index = " << element.index()
                  << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Nothing in the standard library, though [it's not hard to write](http://reedbeta.com/blog/python-like-enumerate-in-cpp17/).

Comment: FWIW, this was the top Google result for `boost enumerate`....

Comment: According to the documentation you can omit the index to start from zero.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I searched for “C++ enumerate” but did not think about adding “boost” to the search terms. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: In C++11 you can use an initializer list, `boost::assign` is no longer necessary here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Indeed, hence "now-redundant" - however I chose to simply reproduce the Boost example verbatim. Readers are of course free to adapt it (lol) as they see fit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using [range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/). A bit more verbose than a handcrafted solution, but it's nice IMHO how you can assemble such a range from existing views.

```
#include <range/v3/view/indices.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

std::vector<int> vec{42, 43, 44};

for (const auto& idxAndValue : view::zip(view::indices, vec))
   std::cout << ideAndValue.first << " : " << idxAndValue.second << "\n";;
```

Comment: Which C++ standard is this? It does not look like C++11, right?

Comment: @MartinUeding C++17, with a library being considered for inclusion in `std` for C++20

Comment: This updated snippet compiles, tested with `clang++ -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that only works:

1. with references to elements, and
2. array-based containers, and
3. elements do not overload `operator&`

```
for(auto const &it : vector) {
    size_t index = &it - vector.data();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately a bit risky -- forgot the `&`? container doesn't have proper reference semantics (`vector<bool>`)? Your `index` is madness and the subtraction has UB. But if you know what you're doing this is certainly a way to get the index if the iteration itself doesn't provide it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Added a note about `operator&`.

Comment: Hadn't even thought of that. `std::addressof` can be your friend there. But now this is getting verbose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, but I'd like to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using an higher-order function. I like it because it's simple to implement and doesn't require you to know the nuances of *structured bindings*. It also doesn't require any extra dependency.

```
template <typename Container, typename F>
void enumerate(Container&& c, F&& f)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for(auto&& x : std::forward<Container>(c)) 
    { 
         f(i++, forward_like<Container>(x)); 
    }
}
```

(Where `forward_like` moves `x` if `Container` is an *rvalue*.)

Usage:

```
enumerate(std::vector{'a', 'b', 'c'}, [](auto index, auto x) 
{
    std::cout << index << ": " << x << '\n';
});
```

Prints:

```
0: 'a'
1: 'b'
2: 'c'
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FBn7YpFTLxAbmdPN)

---

C++11 compliant version: [**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YwhMqCeWNtWM3Ssn)

Comment: Generic lambdas are since C++14 only. Still, this isn't bad :)

Comment: The Haskell part of me really likes this! Unfortunately the code that I currently work on is a high performance production code, where we have to be grateful for using even C++11. I'd like to keep this answer, perhaps we can use it in five years.

Comment: @MartinUeding: you can use this in C++11, just replace `auto` in the lambda with the concrete type of the object.

Comment: @MartinUeding: added C++11-compliant version in the answer.